# Calculating Interest Accrued With an Uneven Interval

Tags: loans, amortization

I'm trying to calculate the interest accrued on my amortization schedule manually. I can calculate it fine if payments are exactly one month apart but this payment is less than 1 month apart.

Last transaction date is 2017-01-01

Next payment is on 2017-01-15 and interest accrued is 362.47 for this payment.

Details of loan

As of `2017-01-01 balance is 350,000`

Compounding `Monthly`

Interest rate `2.7%`

May I ask how was 362.47 calculated?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The interest *compounds* monthly but *accrues* daily.  I'm guessing (since the math results in the same answer) that the accrual method is ACT/365, meaning that the amount of accrued interest is calculated based on the actual number of days divided by 365.

With a $350,000 principal balance, the interest that accrues in 14 days (from the 1st to the 15th) is

```
$350,000 * 2.7% * (14 / 365) = $362.4658 (rounds to $362.47)
```

Comment: Great answer @D Stanley. What if it's crossing over 2 diff day count intervals. 2016-12-20 and payment is made 2017-01-10. And accrual method is ACT/ACT.

Comment: Then you calculate two interest accrual periods and add the accrued amounts - one through 12-31 and one from 01-01 through 01-10.

Comment: How does this formula take into account the *monthly* compounding of the stated interest rate?

Comment: @DJohnM It doesn't.  The compounding would increase the principal amount monthly (and similarly a payment would reduce it).  The formula above only accounts for the interest accrued between compound/payment periods.

Answer (score 0):

Interest accrued is Principal ($350,000) * interest rate (0.027) / per day (365) * days since last payment (14).